# Is it possible to write polymorphic Postgres functions using RECORD parameters?

Tags: postgresql

I want to write a PL/pgSQL function that can take records of different types, check the type of record provided, then do something with the record. Example:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION polymorphic_input(arg_rec RECORD) RETURNS TEXT LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$plpgsql$
BEGIN
  IF pg_typeof(arg_rec)::text = 'information_schema.tables' THEN
    RETURN (arg_rec::information_schema.tables).table_name;
  ELSIF pg_typeof(arg_rec)::text = 'information_schema.columns' THEN
    RETURN (arg_rec::information_schema.columns).column_name;
  ELSE
    RETURN 'unknown';
  END IF;
END;
$plpgsql$;
```

When you call the function with a row from the `information_schema.tables` table, it should return the name of the table and it does so when you call it like this:

```sql
-- this returns table name "pg_type"
SELECT polymorphic_input((SELECT t FROM information_schema.tables t WHERE table_name = 'pg_type' LIMIT 1));
```

When you call the function with a row from the `information_schema.columns` table, it should return the name of the column and it does so when you call it like this:

```sql
-- this returns column name "objsubid"
SELECT polymorphic_input((SELECT t FROM information_schema.columns t WHERE t.column_name = 'objsubid' LIMIT 1));
```

**The problem is you CAN'T call the function twice in a row with different row types**. For example, if you call it with a row from `information_schema.columns` it works, then when you call it with a row form `information_schema.tables`, you get an error like this:

> type of parameter 1 (information_schema.tables) does not match that when preparing the plan (information_schema.columns)

The words **"when preparing the plan"** gave me a hint that Postgres is caching the plans, so I figured running `DISCARD PLANS;` before each call to the function would work, and indeed it does when you run this entire query:

```sql
DISCARD PLANS; SELECT polymorphic_input((SELECT t FROM information_schema.tables t WHERE table_name = 'pg_type' LIMIT 1));
DISCARD PLANS; SELECT polymorphic_input((SELECT t FROM information_schema.columns t WHERE t.column_name = 'objsubid' LIMIT 1));
```

Running `DISCARD PLANS;` seems like the nuclear option and would no doubt affect performance in a real-world scenario. After some experimentation, **I saw that using the `pg_typeof` function is what forces the plans to be cached**. We can rewrite the function to avoid `pg_typeof` by adding a parameter that specifies what record type to expect:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION polymorphic_input2(arg_rec RECORD, arg_type text) RETURNS TEXT LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$plpgsql$
BEGIN
  IF arg_type = 'tables' THEN
    RETURN (arg_rec::information_schema.tables).table_name;
  ELSIF arg_type = 'columns' THEN
    RETURN (arg_rec::information_schema.columns).column_name;
  ELSE
    RETURN 'unknown';
  END IF;
END;
$plpgsql$;
```

You can then **call `polymorphic_input2` multiple times in a row with different row types without error** as follows:

```sql
-- no need for DISCARD PLANS here...these calls work fine.
SELECT polymorphic_input2((SELECT t FROM information_schema.tables t WHERE table_name = 'pg_type' LIMIT 1), 'tables');
SELECT polymorphic_input2((SELECT t FROM information_schema.columns t WHERE t.column_name = 'objsubid' LIMIT 1), 'columns');
```

The problem with `polymorphic_input2` is that you have to manually give it a hint as to the type of the record to expect. **My question: is it possible to implement a polymorphic function that can figure out the type of record passed to it, without the cached plan errors?**

The docs mention the [plan_cache_mode](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-query.html#GUC-PLAN-CACHE_MODE) setting:

> Prepared statements (either explicitly prepared or **implicitly generated, for example by PL/pgSQL**) can be executed using custom or generic plans. **Custom plans are made afresh for each execution using its specific set of parameter values,** while generic plans do not rely on the parameter values and can be re-used across executions....The allowed values are auto (the default), force_custom_plan and force_generic_plan...

I tried removing the error by running `SET plan_cache_mode = force_custom_plan;` but that didn't help (which is probably a bug because the docs imply it should force a custom plan in each call, but Postgres is still caching the plan and causing errors). Only `DISCARD PLANS` worked.

The docs on [plan caching](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-implementation.html#PLPGSQL-VAR-SUBST) seem to recognize this issue and say:

> The **mutable nature of record variables presents another problem** in this connection. When fields of a record variable are used in expressions or statements, the data types of the fields must not change from one call of the function to the next, since each expression will be analyzed using the data type that is present when the expression is first reached. **EXECUTE can be used to get around this problem when necessary.**

...and a little further down the docs indicate this shouldn't be happening:

> Likewise, **functions having polymorphic argument types have a separate statement cache for each combination of actual argument types** they have been invoked for, **so that data type differences do not cause unexpected failures**.

This is further confirmed by the [docs `EXECUTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) which say:

> Also, **there is no plan caching for commands executed via EXECUTE**. Instead, the command is always planned each time the statement is run. Thus the command string can be dynamically created within the function to perform actions on different tables and columns.

So I tried another variant that tries to run `pg_typeof` via `EXECUTE`:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION polymorphic_input3(arg_rec RECORD) RETURNS TEXT LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$plpgsql$
DECLARE
  rec_type text;
BEGIN
  EXECUTE 'SELECT pg_typeof($1)' INTO rec_type USING arg_rec;
  IF rec_type = 'information_schema.tables' THEN
    RETURN (arg_rec::information_schema.tables).table_name;
  ELSIF rec_type = 'information_schema.columns' THEN
    RETURN (arg_rec::information_schema.columns).column_name;
  ELSE
    RETURN 'unknown';
  END IF;
END;
$plpgsql$;
```

...but that still produces the same error as the variant which calls `pg_typeof` directly.

**My question once again: is it possible (in Postgres 14) to implement a polymorphic function that can figure out the type of record passed to it, without the cached plan errors?**

**UPDATE (25/Aug/2023)** a little over one year later it appears the answer is YES! Thanks to [Conor's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76968818/3370431) below, it seems you can use `ANYCOMPATIBLE` as the argument type and `pg_typeof` will now work without errors. Here is the modified function:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION polymorphic_input2(arg_rec ANYCOMPATIBLE) RETURNS TEXT LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$plpgsql$
BEGIN
    IF pg_typeof(arg_rec)::text = 'tables' THEN
        RETURN (arg_rec::information_schema.tables).table_name;
    ELSIF pg_typeof(arg_rec)::text = 'columns' THEN
        RETURN (arg_rec::information_schema.columns).column_name;
    ELSE
        RETURN 'unknown: ' || pg_typeof(arg_rec);
    END IF;
END;
$plpgsql$;
```

You can now call the above passing it different record types as follows:

```sql
/* The query below will return the name of the table which is "pg_type" */
SELECT polymorphic_input2((SELECT t FROM information_schema.tables t WHERE table_name = 'pg_type' LIMIT 1));

/* The query below will return the name of the column which is "objsubid" */
SELECT polymorphic_input2((SELECT t FROM information_schema.columns t WHERE t.column_name = 'objsubid' LIMIT 1));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this answers the question, but if you use the `ANYCOMPATIBLE` type in the function definition you can avoid some errors:

```sql
DROP FUNCTION polymorphic_input(arg_rec ANYCOMPATIBLE);
CREATE FUNCTION polymorphic_input(arg_rec ANYCOMPATIBLE) RETURNS TEXT
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$plpgsql$
BEGIN
  IF pg_typeof(arg_rec) IN ('integer', 'numeric') THEN
    RETURN 'number';
  ELSIF pg_typeof(arg_rec)::TEXT IN ('date') THEN
    RETURN 'date';
  ELSE
    RETURN 'unknown';
  END IF;
END;
$plpgsql$;

SELECT polymorphic_input(5); -- number
SELECT polymorphic_input(date('2022-01-01')); -- date
SELECT polymorphic_input('2022-01-01'); -- unknown
```

Comment: +1 this is awesome! I marked it as the answer because using `ANYCOMPATIBLE` as the argument type now allows `pg_typeof()` to work its magic without caching plans. I updated my question with the modified function using `ANYCOMPATIBLE`.

Comment: @Conor Would you care to elaborate on your bounty criteria? My understanding is OP's function sets up a map saying which column to pick from a record, based on what table the record originated from - the `IF`/`CASE` seems adequate. The only *repetition* I see in both examples is the `IF`s repeating the same check while a [`CASE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONDITIONALS) could test once then list possible options. [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/ztYHU1BF)

Comment: @Zegarek the main issue was errors being thrown with the original solution, and no errors thrown in my proposed answer. The bounty was to incentivize anyone to give a better answer (e.g. a more specific reason why ANYCOMPATIBLE works, or a different approach). In other words, the CASE/IF statement is not eligible for a bounty as it does not materially improve the quality of the answer.